# Google App Engine app has periods when it returns empty response instead of actual data

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

I have a small service discovery service running on Google App Engine free tier. It queries Google Cloud Datastore with simplest queries on the data that is virtually static. Recently we had incidents that the service was returning empty results. That was going on for 12 hours. After that results came back to normal. We only recently noticed it. In the logs I see at least 3 incidents like that.

I logged into a console and saw:

- 0 app errors
- 0 server errors
- all green GCE status
- max used quota is just 5%
- intervals of time where every response is 204

I see absolutely no reason to receive an empty response and yet they are sometimes empty. I see no way to notify Google that there is cloud-side problems, since this is a free tier account with no support.

So, is there anything I might have missed?

UPD: As I look into the code, the only way to get 204+empty body is to have exception in getting an instance of `javax.jdo.PersistenceManager` or a new instance of `javax.jdo.Query`. So it is less likely that Cloud Datastore is at fault, because if the result would be empty, app should answer 200+`[]`, if there was an error during a query, app should answer 204+`<h1>Exception</h1>...`.

But again, I don't see how request could work now, but not work 5 minutes ago.

UPD2: The app was stable for more than two years.

Comment: What library (and version) are you using to access Cloud Datastore?

Comment: @JimMorrison the one provided by App Engine SDK- `com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.9.30/appengine-java-sdk-1.9.30/lib/opt/user/datanucleus/v2/jdo-api-3.0.1.jar`

Comment: and no one from GCP is concerned by this, plus no means to reach anyone. That's all you should know about GCP.

Comment: Same problem today.